# How to prevent history entries with a web extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

How to prevent browser to make history entry with a webextension. 
(My goal is to disable history based on the tabId).

For now, I managed to delete an url from history based of the navigated pages but it also deletes past visit of the url. (exemple of the problem: If I go to the page and then activate webextension and navigate to the same page both will be deleted from history).

```
browser.webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded.addListener((details)=>{
   var prom = browser.history.deleteUrl({url: details.url})    
});
```

My target platform is Firefox but if you find something that work on google chrome, it will probably work on Firefox.

Comment: In Firefox you should use [contextualIdentities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/contextualIdentities) for this functionality. In Chrome there's no solution except incognito mode. You can probably use an iframe (to put the page inside) but it won't work with some sites.

Comment: I thinked that contextualIdentities were completely independent from history. And only managed session (cookies, local storage). If there is a way to do that,  I would love to know how.

Comment: I guess I'm wrong about contextualIdentities, in which case there's only an incognito mode.

Comment: It's not possible in a straightforward way. I have opened a bug report here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1638344